# Loading Server Side Rendered Templates in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates

As a NodeJS developer who needs to render some HTML service side, I'm spoilt for choice when it comes to template languages -- mustache, handlebars, doT, Dust, EJS, etc.  I could probably use a different template module every day of the month if I wanted.

However, as I research most of these template modules, I've found they all (seem to?) work with templates that are already loaded into Javascript as a string.  For example, this is the hello world example from the [EJS GitHub README](https://github.com/tj/ejs) -- your template goes in the `str` variable.

```
ejs.compile(str, options);
// => Function

ejs.render(str, options);
```

Is there a generally accepted way (i.e. "best practice") on how to store and load these sorts of templates in a server-side javascript application?  (On disk loaded with the `fs` module? Something else?)

Bonus points: Is there a template module that has this functionality built in?

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers I've received elsewhere -- this usually isn't the job of the template module in node applications, and direct use of the `fs` libraries is the way to go.

Two engines that *do* have this sort of system are [pug](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html) and [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#include).